# profile: accepted answer statistics and search

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, user-profile

Is it possible to see the percentage of answers in a user-profile that were 'accepted answers' and search or sort his list of answers for accepted answers?

If not this would be a nice to have feature. The accepted answers of a user are often the most interesting for others to read.

This could even get some badges for 100 accepted answers or 100 answers and an accepted rate of n% or more. I'm not sure, what percentage value would make sense here, would depend on the average accept rate per user.

Answer (score 2):

I asked for this [on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2238/would-it-be-useful-so-show-peoples-hit-rate-i-e-percentage-of-answers-accep) way back in June 2009.

The only thing to come out of that appeared to be the accept rate of questions - not on answers.

I agree it would be nice statistic to have. Not sure about the badges though.